# Java Static Method, Wildcard / Generic Return Type

Tags: java, generics, functional-java

I'm building an API, which uses abstract classes, to invoke static methods. Some Java Pseudocode:

```
public abstract class APIBaseClass {

    public static List<?> myMethod(Class<?> clazz, MyConverter converter, List<Object> objects) {
        return objects.stream()
                  .map(object -> converter.convertObjectToType(object, clazz))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

And, where `myMethod` is invoked:

```
public abstract class MyAPIClass extends APIBaseClass {

    public static List<MyClassType> invokingMethod(MyConverter converter, List<Object> objects) {
        List<MyClassType> list = myMethod(MyClassType.class, converter, objects);
        ...
        return list;
    }
}
```

`myMethod` compiles, as expected. And, `invokingMethod` does not compile, also as expected, due to incompatible types:

```
Required: List<blah.blah.blah.MyClassType>
Found:    List<capture<?>>
```

It compiles without errors or warnings if I: (1) @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") on `invokingMethod`, and (2) cast the result of `myMethod` to a list of `MyClassType`, when invoked, i.e. `List<MyClassType> list = (List<MyClassType>) myMethod(MyClassType.class, converter, objects);`. However, there's no transparency that this would be necessary to anybody using the API, which feels less than ideal.

What are my options for `myMethod` returning the a list of the type it is invoked with to `invokingMethod`, while maintaining my abstract classes and static methods, while ideally improving usability within `invokingMethod`?

Any suggestions or alternative ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `myMethod(MyClassType.class, objectsList)` is not same as `myMethod(Class<?> clazz, MyConverter converter, List<Object> objects)`?

Comment: Also did you mean `objects ` instead of `objectsList`?

Comment: @tsolakp, yes. I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your classes are abstract is completely irrelevant. If you make them abstract to prevent their instantiation, and use inheritance to avoid having to specify the class name, then that's an antipattern, which doesn't use abstract classes for polymorphism as they're intended to be used. Just add a private constructor to the classes, and use static imports.

Now, regarding the question itself, you need to make the method generic, and the `MyConverter.convertObjectToType()` method generic, too:

```
public static <T> List<T> myMethod(Class<T> clazz, MyConverter converter, List<Object> objects) {
    return objects.stream()
              .map(object -> converter.convertObjectToType(object, clazz))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: They were made abstract to avoid instantiation, yes. But, I see your point in that it lays out an antipattern. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Generics require a class to be instantiated though, correct? Is this the reason for your suggestion of a private constructor? Or, is that to correct the antipattern?

Comment: No. Methods can be generic, including static methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html. BTW, Collectors.toList(), that you're using in your code, is such a static generic method. And the private constructor has nothing to do with generics: it allows preventing the instantiation of the class.

Comment: Thank you. I had to sit with your answer for a few minutes to understand it. You're right. Thank you for the answer and explanation. The `<T>` between `static` and `List` was what had me hung up on this.